# how to tell if you fall down your head will *** the floor?

Tags: formality, speech

how to say in the below scenario...

> if you fall down in the floor, your head will _ _ _ _ _ _ in the floor.

the blank should talk about the crashing of head with the floor. What is the correct form to use while speaking with a kid.

Comment: I have heard "your head will **bonk** on the floor" which sounds like the noise actually made when that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use *hit* for kids.

> if you fall down in the floor, your head will *hit* the floor.

*Strike* would be more appropriate for adults.

> if you fall down in the floor, your head will *strike* the floor.

Although I would not use *will*. I suggest *could*:

> if you fall down in the floor, your head *could* hit the floor.

because your head might not hit the floor.

Comment: I would use _hit_ with adults as well. _Strike_ is very formal, to me.

Comment: @Colin To me, strike is more formal, but not *very* formal. Interesting how one's local culture and experience colours our language and perceptions. And good for fSazy to see differing views :-)

Comment: @andy256: OK, perhaps _very formal_ was an exaggeration. But _strike_ in this sense is not in my everyday vocabulary.

Comment: Good to know that.